# Why is this comma needed in the Declaration of Independence?

Tags: legalese, punctuation, commas

Regarding **the comma** after *the earth*:

> When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, **and to assume among the powers of the earth,** the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.

As I can understand, there's no hard rules in English regarding use of punctuation marks, so one can put them simply anywhere if it makes the meaning of a sentence clearer. Yes?

Comment: *one people..??*

Comment: @MaulikV "People" is also a singular noun, meaning the members of a particular nation, community or ethnic group.

Comment: @DavidRicherby do you mean a 'mass noun'? Still, *one* people!

Comment: @MaulikV No, I mean a singular noun. The Americans are one people; the British are one people; the Americans and the British are two peoples (and about 380 million people, in the other sense of the word).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Okai! Got it! *They are a rich people!* -for example. But don't you think it's better call that as 'countable noun' rather than 'singular noun'?

Comment: @Maulik V count nouns are by definition singular or plural. "a noun, as apple, table, or birthday, that typically refers to a countable thing and that in English can be used in both the singular and the plural and can be preceded by the indefinite article a or an and by numerals."

Comment: @Maulik V this is when 'people' means *the entire body of persons who constitute a community or other group by virtue of a common culture, religion, or the like*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation originally reflected natural syntactic pauses. Since the phrase "among the powers of the earth" interrupts the main verb-phrase  "to assume ... the separate and equal station" in order to qualify it, a natural syntactic pause occurs after "earth":

> When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one
>   people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with
>   another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and
>   equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle
>   them...